# Regex grep file contents and invoke command

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file that has been generated containing MD5 info along with filenames. I'm wanting to remove the files from the directory they are in. I'm not sure how to go about doing this exactly.

filelist (file) contains:

```
MD5 (dupe) = 1fb218dfef4c39b4c8fe740f882f351a
MD5 (somefile) = a5c6df9fad5dc4299f6e34e641396d38
```

my command (which i would like to include with `rm`) looks like this:

```
grep -o "\((.*)\)" filelist
```

returns this:

```
(dupe)
(somefile)
```

*almost good, although the parentheses need to be eliminated (not sure how). I tried using `grep -Po "(?<=\().*(?=\))" filelist` using a lookahead/lookaround, but the command didn't work.

The next thing I would like to do is take the output filenames and delete them from the directory they are in. I'm not sure how to script it, but it would essentially do:

```
<returned results from grep>
rm dupe $target
rm somefile $target
```

Comment: What is $target that you're passing to your rm commands? Is it correct to assume you just want to run: rm dupe and rm somefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take lines like these

```
MD5 (dupe) = 1fb218dfef4c39b4c8fe740f882f351a
MD5 (somefile) = a5c6df9fad5dc4299f6e34e641396d38
```

extract the second column without the parentheses to get the filenames

```
dupe
somefile
```

and then delete the files?

Assuming the filenames don't have spaces, try this:

```
# this is where your duplicate files are.
dupe_directory='/some/path'

# Check that you found the right files:
awk '{print $2}' file-with-md5-lines.txt | tr -d '()' | xargs -I{} ls -l "$dupe_directory/{}"

# Looks ok, delete:
awk '{print $2}' file-with-md5-lines.txt | tr -d '()' | xargs -I{} rm -v "$dupe_directory/{}"
```

`xargs -I{}` means to replace the argument (dupe filename) with {} so it can be used in a more complex command.

Comment: hi - how would i specify which directory to remove the files from? thanks!

Comment: That depends. Are they all in the same directory or scattered all over the place? If scattered, where is the directory information? I'll update my answer if you explain the situation and give an example of the layout.

Comment: all in the same directory, but not necessarily the `pwd` or one i'm currently in.

Comment: Ok, then you just put your *file-with-md5-lines.txt* in the same directory as the dupe-files and run the exact commands above. **Or**: `cd` to the directory where the dupe-files are, then run the commands with */full/path/to/file-with-md5-lines.txt*. The first command will help you check that you found all the right files before deleting them.

Comment: so you're saying there's no way to specify which directory unless it's done one of those two ways? ultimately i'd rather not have the filelist in the directory or have to manually cd to it.

Comment: You want to execute the commands from some other place and specify the directory in the commands after `xargs`? No problem, I can update my answer if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes, i basically need it to be `script can reside anywhere`, `filelist is in location 1`, `remove files in location 2` - thanks

Comment: Answer has been updated. Set $dupe_directory and you can run it from anywhere

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44257/discussion-between-grebneke-and-cocoa-puffs)

Answer (score 1):

The tool you're looking for is xargs: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs
It's pretty standard on *nix systems.

UPDATE: Given that target equals the directory where the files live...

I believe the syntax would look something like:

`yourgrepcmd | xargs -I{} rm "$target{}"`

The -I creates a placeholder string, and each line from your grep command gets inserted there.

UPDATE:

The step you need to remove the parens is a little use of sed's substitution command (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Something like this:

`cat filelist | sed "s/MD5 (\([^)]*\)) .*$/\1/" | xargs -I{} rm "$target/{}"`

The moral of the story here is, if you learn to utilize sed and xargs (or awk if you want something a little more advanced) you'll be a more capable linux user.

Comment: hi - the command works for removing the files, although it removes them from `pwd` instead of `$target`, `target = /some/other/directory/`